# How to use COUNT aggregator inside HAVING clause in knex.js?

Tags: database, query-builder, knex.js, having, objection.js

```
let duplicates = await Books.query()
                  .select('book_id')
                  .groupBy('book_id')
                  .having(knex.count('book_id'), '>', 1);
```

Here I want to use the count aggregator inside the having clause. How can I do that inside knex.having() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a small snippet of `knex.raw` is probably the easiest way.

```js
let duplicates = await Books.query()
                  .select('book_id')
                  .groupBy('book_id')
                  .having(knex.raw('count(book_id) > 1'));
```

Or if you want to properly escape your column name with backticks you can use a `??` positional argument

```js
let duplicates = await Books.query()
                  .select('book_id')
                  .groupBy('book_id')
                  .having(knex.raw('count(??) > 1', 'book_id'));
```

Comment: I think knex should have something like .havingCount() method....